# changing Images src with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, attr

I'm using this code for changing image src but its not working. if i'm write for variables text values fox example:

```
track = '212';
artist = 'azealea banks';
```

It's changing only last images src but when I'm getting this variables values from neighbor span it's not working at all.

My jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
    $(".plimg").attr("src",

    function (index) {
        var title = $(this).next('span.titletrack').text();
        alert(title);
        var array = title.split(' - ');
        var track = array[0];
        var artist = array[1];

        var output;

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.search",
            data: {
                track: track,
                artist: artist,
                api_key: "ca86a16ce762065a423e20381ccfcdf0",
                format: "json",
                lang: "en",
                limit: 1
            },
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                output = data.results.trackmatches.track.image[0]["#text"];
            }

        });
        return output;
    });
});
```

and HTML

```
<div id="playlist" class="scrollable" style="height: 300px;overflow-y: auto">
    <li>
        <img src="/img/playlist/33a - Sulis Vardo.jpg">
<span class="titletrack">33a - Sulis Vardo</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="plimg" src="/img/playlist/33a - Shota.jpg">
        <span onclick="playinToplaylist($(this).html());" class="titletrack">33a - Shota</span>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Why a function inside of the function? This way it has little use. Just set iets value to a variable and set that to the image

Comment: Eeeck.  Synchronous ajax is very bad for the user experience - locks up the browser during the call.

Comment: and can you write answer (corrected code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a couple of changes. Firstly it's only finding the last image because only the last image in your HTML has the `plimg` class, so I've added that:

```
<div id="playlist" class="scrollable" style="height: 300px;overflow-y: auto">
    <li>
        <img class="plimg"/>
        <span class="titletrack">33a - Sulis Vardo</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="plimg"/>
        <span onclick="playinToplaylist($(this).html());" class="titletrack">33a - Shota</span>
    </li>
</div>
```

Secondly I've changed the JavaScript to iterate over the images and load the image sources asynchronously. If you check the response to the ajax call the details passed for the second image do not return any image data, so that's why that one isn't loaded.

```
$(function(){
    $("img.plimg").each(function() {
        var img = $(this);
        var title = img.next("span.titletrack").text();
        var titleDetails = title.split(' - ');
        var track = titleDetails[0];
        var artist = titleDetails[1];

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.search",
            data: {
                track: track,
                artist: artist,
                api_key: "ca86a16ce762065a423e20381ccfcdf0",
                format: "json",
                lang: "en",
                limit: 1
            },
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                var trackData = data.results.trackmatches.track;
                if(!trackData){
                    alert("No track data for " + artist + " / " + track);
                    return;
                }
                var output = trackData.image[0]["#text"];
                img.attr("src", output);
            }
        });            
    });
});
```

I've put these updates on a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/penjA/2).